# Flexible gutters without using 100% width?

Tags: width, percentage, css

So, I am designing with a fixed width. I just want the gutters to be flexible. So, I tried just using parent div's with 100% width. As you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/115/

What I intended was for what is happening with the fixed div ("nav" div) to happen. When the user window gets too small, I'd like the 100% width to collapse upon the fixed width elements (in this case, 1000px) and enable horizontal scrolling.

However, my parent width:100% does not work like that with relative positioning. The "top" "title" and "container" divs all stop at whereever the screen stops. I suppose that is 100% but it leaves the fixed width content overflowing these (now) smaller parent divs!

Additionally, the problem also shows up when a vertical scrollbar comes down. The area to the vertical scrollbar is considered 100% and the remaining gets left blank. This also creates a horizontal scrollbar to view this "extra" part.

What is the best solution here? Should I abandon my parent div 100% width approach?

I've tried making the these 100% divs have min-width:1000px, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm just a bit stumped here.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've read about this before.  Before you can use 100% in a div width you must set the css of both your body and html tags to 100%.

```
 html,body{
 width: 100%;
 }
```

or else it will stop at the edge of the screen on any device.

Comment: Another problem you may be having is using float.  For some reason, whenever float is used it doesn't care too much about its parent container and may overflow it.  I have mainly ran into this problem with height.  But, I'm sure that it may be a problem with width too.

Comment: Hmmm... it can't be float. The only elements there that are floating are the "cont" and "exsi" divs. I removed the entire "containerwide" div leaving only "nav" "top" and "title"... it still happens. The 100% stops at the screen width and disregards the child's fixed width. It also won't stop for min-width either. The fixed position div ("nav") works perfectly... but that's fixed and I can't have that. Maybe static or absolute instead? But will need to see how changing that position impacts things... if they work at all. Bleh.